# Disallowing Pasting capabilities in Specific columns based on selected Data Validation while still enabling pasting in the same Data validation column

Tags: excel, vba, validation, copy-paste, restriction

First off let me start by saying I am very new to any form of Coding, VBA is my first attempt at learning it and I am not learning it quickly.

My problem is I have a sheet that I have the intention of giving to vendors for them to fill our product information. I provided drop downs and tried to create some formulas to reduce the work that the vendor had to do, while also controlling what data I get back makes sense. Unfortunately, the vendors decided to copy and paste overtop of the Drop down options which override the data validation, making the efforts I initially put in redundant, while simultaneously removing any form of data standardization.

I would like to create some code that will enable me to restrict the ability to copy and paste cells that

1. Do not contain data validation
2. is a different type of Data validation than what is assigned to that column
3. maintains copy and pasting of the cells within a specific column into the same column
   ex. Column E:E has 3 values that can be selected from (red, blue, yellow). Column G:G has 5 values that can be selected from (Volkswagen, Volvo, MINI, Mercedes, Jaguar) I would like E:E to be able to past inside of column E but not into Column G even though both have data validation.

I followed a thread that was previously made a long time ago:

[INITIAL SOURCE THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147984/prevent-copying-and-pasting-a-cell-from-a-column-with-data-validation-to-another#comment27891470_18154293)

[SECONDARY SOURCE THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977088/avoid-multiple-error-pop-up-messages-in-excel)

In the secondary Source thread, there is a discussion that helps describe my exact challenge but does not lead anywhere in the comments of the Answer

Below is the Code I am using

```
`Dim boolDontShowAgain As Boolean

 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     On Error GoTo Whoa

      Application.EnableEvents = False

 'Does the validation range still have validation?
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!A3:A999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!G3:G999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!H3:H999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!I3:I999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!O3:O999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!P3:P999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!Q3:Q999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!R3:R999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!S3:S999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!R3:R999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!AF3:AF999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!AG3:AG999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!BG3:BG999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!BH3:BH999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!BR3:BR999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!BS3:BS999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!CG3:CG999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!CH3:CH999")) Then RestoreValidation
 If Not HasValidation(Range("PIM - MASTER DATA!CI3:CI999")) Then RestoreValidation

 Letscontinue:
     Application.EnableEvents = True
     Exit Sub
 Whoa:
     MsgBox Err.Description
     Resume Letscontinue
 End Sub

 Private Sub RestoreValidation()
     Application.Undo
     If boolDontShowAgain = False Then
         MsgBox "Your last operation was canceled." & _
         "It would have deleted data validation rules.", vbCritical
         boolDontShowAgain = True
     End If
 End Sub

 Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
     On Error Resume Next
     Debug.Print r.Validation.Type
     If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True
 End Function`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, the conditions for columns are set to 1 (A) and 5 (E), and not trigger for row 1 (cell.Row > 1). Adjust as needed for your specific columns and rows.

```
Dim AllowUndo As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Check if undo operation is allowed
    If AllowUndo Then
        AllowUndo = False
        GoTo ExitProcedure
    End If
    
    For Each cell In Target
        If (cell.Column = 1 And Not HasValidation(cell) And cell.Row > 1) Or _
           (cell.Column = 5 And Not HasValidation(cell) And cell.Row > 1) Then
            GoTo RestoreValidation
        End If
    Next cell

ExitProcedure:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

RestoreValidation:
    MsgBox "Your last operation was canceled." & _
           "It would have deleted data validation rules.", vbCritical
    
    ' Enable undo operation
    AllowUndo = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Undo
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitProcedure
End Sub

Private Function HasValidation(r As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = Not IsEmpty(r.Validation.Type)
End Function
```

Comment: Ok, great this works for the first half of what I am trying to achieve! which is further than I had previously gotten. However, now I am hoping to prevent copying from one column of drop down menus to another column of drop down menus. Right now If a cell has no validation and is pasted into the drop down cell the error pops us. However if I take a cell that has a drop down validation and paste it into another column that has drop down validation the newly pasted drop down menu overrights the previous drop down menu. can we prevent this from happening, while maintaining inter column pasting?